# Problem with library node SPFx

Tags: spfx, error, pnp, spfx-tooling, npm

I have trouble downloading `npm install @pnp/spfx-controls-react`, has anyone happened to it?

It shows me the following error, I have removed and installed node again, but the problem persists

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can install again with --verbose on the end to show more details about the error.